# Задача на событие клика мыши js

Tags: javascript

Недавно начал изучать js и решил  придумать какую нибудь задачку, и не смог её решить.

Собственно вот задача.

При нажатие на `<b class="itemAdd">i</b>`  переменная balance должна увеличиваться на значения указанная в `<b class="item_price">span</b>`.

```html
<h4>
  <a class="predmet" href="#">
    <i class="itemAdd">тут должна быть иконка корзинки</i>
  </a>
  <span id=" item_price">$ 310</span>
</h4>
```

Comment: решение писать не буду а идея следующая: вешаете событие на клик елемента с класом itemAdd (https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener, дальше сами) потом получаете текст с  item_price(например так https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling)  преборазуете его в целое число (parseInt) а потом делате остальные действия.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно тебя понял:

```js
let balance = 0;

document.querySelector('.itemAdd').addEventListener("click", (event)=>{
    event.preventDefault();
    let sum = document.querySelector('#item_price').textContent;
  sum = parseInt(sum.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ""), 10);
  balance=balance+sum;
  alert ("balance= "+ balance);
});
```

```html
<h4><a class="predmet" href="#"><i class="itemAdd">тут должна быть иконка корзинки</i></a> <span id="item_price">$ 310</span></h4>
```